# PyQGIS save a project and close a project - QGIS v3

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

Using PyQGIS with QGIS v3

My script opens an empty QGIS project (thinking this would retain the path).
I add some layers, perform a few tasks. All is good.

Now I want to close the project or I should say update the project and then close.  Similar to clicking on Project / Save and then I guess Project / New to close out the project with a new empty project.

I have yet to find any way for what I thought would be the simplest of commands.  I've tried

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
project.write
```

Thought this would be an easy find but I am having no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You must looking for `project.write()` + `project.clear()`. Aren't you ? You can then add a condition that will trigger the Save/Close. You can also build a loop through the folder containing all your .qgz files to avoid the manuel opening.